# gawk ten times slower with LANG set to UTF-8 compared with LANG=C

Tags: gawk

I have two identical servers in terms of hardware (actually vm's), one at RHEL 4.7, one at RHEL 6.

On RHEL6 gawk is very much slower. I did a simple test involving processing 3.7M lines of text, with a simple gawk command.

On RH4.7, gawk 3.1.3 I get:

`time gawk '/^pat1/&&/pat2/ {x++};END {print "x="x}' file`

x=40874

real    0m7.266s
user    0m6.809s
sys     0m0.460s

On RH6, gawk 3.1.7 I get same x result, with times:

`real    1m28.138s
user    1m27.657s
sys     0m0.453s`

7s vs 1m28s !  Initially I thought something had happened to the vm after upgrade, but other tests of CPU (e.g. gzips, the same program in perl) produce similar results on each.
So it seems to be down to gawk. 
Not sure this is the correct place to ask, but are there known performance problems with gawk 3.1.7 on RH 6?  Where's the best place to find out, if not here?

Comment: try posting to comp.lang.awk on google groups. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from the gawk bugs mailing list.

It is all down to the locale setting. On my RH6 box LANG was set to en_US.UTF-8, on RH4 it was C. Changing it on RH6 fixed the performance.

Definitely worth remembering - gawk was 10x slower with LANG set to UTF-8 compared with C